# combobox text still showing previous value on change

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am using 1 combobox to populate a 2nd combobox. What is happening however, is that the 2nd combobox dropdown is changing and displaying the correct values but when the change occurs, the text property still retains the old value. I am using items.clear() and thought that would also clear the text value of the combobox.

I am using winforms and would be grateful if someone could point out my newbie error. Thanks

```
Private Sub cmbCustomer_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmbCustomer.SelectedIndexChanged

        ' This is the routine to populate the departments box with values from customer

        sql = "SELECT * from Departments WHERE Customer = ?"

        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", cmbCustomer.Text)

        cmd.CommandText = sql
        cmd.Connection = oledbCnn
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        cmbDept.Items.Clear()
        cmbRequestBy.Items.Clear()

        While dr.Read()

            cmbDept.Items.Add(dr("Name"))

        End While

        cmd.Dispose()
        dr.Close()
        'oledbCnn.Close()


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are clearing the Items collection not the Text property of the combo.

This behavior depends on the [`DropDownStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.comboboxstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of the combobox. 
The default is `DropDown` that allow the combo to maintain separate inner controls for Items (A List of some kind) and Text (a TextBox)

If you change the property to `DropDownList` clearing the Items collection will clear also the 'text' part of it.

Of course you loose the possibility to type inside the TextBox portion of the combobox for example to add an item not included in the list

See [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/804944/combobox-item-clear-does-not-clear-any-text-in-the-textbox-portion) for Microsoft Response to similar question

Comment: Steve, if I wnated to keep the textbox aspect, how would I clear the textbox element. Thanks

Comment: Simply call ComboBox.Text = string.Empty or [CombBox.ResetText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f16139cd(v=vs.110).aspx)